# Return a function as argument in SICP example average-damp

Tags: elisp

I tried the following higher-order function from [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3.4):

```
(defun average-damp(f)
  (lambda (x) (average x (f x))))
(defun average(x y)
     (/ (+ x y) 2.0))
(defun square(x)
  (* x x))
((average-damp square) 10)
```

> Namely, given a function f, we consider the function whose value at x
>   is equal to the average of x and f(x).

But running it reports an error:

```
progn: Invalid function: (average-damp square)
```

I verified that `square` and `average` work correctly. Here's the original version `average-damp` in Scheme:

```
(define (average-damp f)
  (lambda (x) (average x (f x))))
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `apply` or `funcall`.  They have similar functionality but accept their arguments differently.

```
(funcall (average-damp square) 10)
```

See also https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html

Comment: The book uses Scheme; replacing Scheme with Emacs Lisp is slightly adventurous. I'm not familiar enough with Scheme to really say, but IIRC this is one of the areas where they differ. https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/bsfj63/sicp_in_elisp/ seems to vaguely corroborate this.

Comment: I got the idea. I will not tried an adventure any more. Scheme is a pure tool to unleash mind power, so it's useless to get real things done.

Comment: Scheme is fine; it's just different to Emacs Lisp.  You're clearly working through SICP, so I urge you to start using one of the many good Scheme interpreters so that you don't keep running into expected differences and having to ask questions about them.  Trying to use Scheme code verbatim *as if it were elisp* is a doomed approach.